# Room Boundaries in Blood Ties

Tags: mansions-of-madness

In Blood Ties, what counts as a room boundary for the purpose of Horror Tests and Item Abilities? (e.g. Elder Sign)

For example, my girlfriend raises a zombie in the graveyard. Do all my investigators out in the open have to take a horror test, or only those in the graveyard?

Alternatively, Gloria Grant is surrounded by 4 zombies, all within 1 range. Does her successful Elder Sign roll drive all the zombies back, or only those that are on her tile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should go by the definition in the rule book on page 8

> **Room** - An area of the map tile that has a name and is separated from the other rooms by solid brown walls, doors, or the edge of the map tile. ...

- Raise a Zombie in the graveyard: Only those in the Graveyard **room**.

> Whenever a monster enters (or is placed) in an investigator's room (or vise versa), the investigator must immediately make an attribute test called a HORROR TEST. ... If multiple investigators are in the room, the must each make a horror test.

- Elder Sign: although poorly worded (the Elder Sign rules text), all monsters in the **room** are moved two **spaces** away from her. (Keep in mind that a map *tile* may have as many as 3 rooms on it, you cannot use the terms interchangeably)

> **Tile** - A single piece of punchboard that contains between one and three rooms.
>
> **Elder Sign** - "Pass: The keeper must move each monster in your room 2 spaces away from you."